# Strange out of range error

Tags: c++, range

In the following code, when I run it, I face a strange out of range error. This code is the answer of one exercise of book Programming Principles and Practice using C++ by Stroustrup.

```
#include <Simple_window.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//-----------------------------------

class Person
{
public:
    Person(string f_n, string s_n, int a) {
        for(int i=0; i<f_n.size() || i<s_n.size(); i++) 
            if(f_n[i] == ';' || f_n[i] == ':' || f_n[i] == '\'' || 
                f_n[i] == '[' || f_n[i] == ']' || f_n[i] == '*'  || 
                f_n[i] == '&' || f_n[i] == '^' || f_n[i] == '%'  ||
                f_n[i] == '$' || f_n[i] == '#' || f_n[i] == '@'  ||
                f_n[i] == '!' ||
                s_n[i] == ';' || s_n[i] == ':' || s_n[i] == '\'' || 
                s_n[i] == '[' || s_n[i] == ']' || s_n[i] == '*'  || 
                s_n[i] == '&' || s_n[i] == '^' || s_n[i] == '%'  ||
                s_n[i] == '$' || s_n[i] == '#' || s_n[i] == '@'  ||
                s_n[i] == '!')
                error("Bad characters!");
        first_name =  f_n;
        second_name = s_n;
        if(a < 0 || a >=150) 
            error ("Bad age!");
        age = a;
    }

    string get_first_name()  { return first_name; }
    string get_second_name() { return second_name; }
    int get_age()     { return age;  }
private:
    string first_name, second_name;
    int age;

};

//-------------------------------------------------------------

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Person& p) {
    string f_n, s_n;
    int a;
    cout <<"Enter first name and second name and age:";
    if(!(is >> f_n >> s_n >> a))
        error("Can't read the object");
    Person pp(f_n,s_n,a);
    p = pp;
    return is;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Person& p) {

    if(!(os << p.get_first_name() <<' '<< p.get_second_name() << p.get_age()))
        error("Can't write the object");
    return os;
}

//------------------------------------------------------

int main() try
{
    Person p("Goofy","tom",53);
    vector <Person> vp;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        cin>>p;
        vp.push_back(p);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<vp.size(); i++)
        cout << vp[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}

catch(exception& e) {
    cerr << e.what();
    return 0;
}
catch(...) {
    return 1;
}
```

The error has to do with line 2 after `int main()` (the `Person p("Goofy","tom",53);`) but I don't know why those `strings` make that error!

this is the error: http://i59.tinypic.com/v487sw.png

Comment: `i<f_n.size() || i<s_n.size()` is wrong! Change to `i<f_n.size() && i<s_n.size()`

Comment: Thank you. Your comment is true and since apparently you posted it sooner that the answer below, please make it as an answer so that I can give it an answer vote.

Comment: @user3724662 Actually I beat him to it by 25 sec if you check the timestamps ;)

Comment: @user3724662 I would have written an answer, if I'd consider this a good question.

Comment: Because you consider professional questions as good ones while forums are more for beginners not professional. never mind, bye.

Comment: @user3724662 _"Because you consider professional questions as good ones ..."_ No, that's not my point. Take a look at [**How do I ask a good question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
i<f_n.size() || i<s_n.size()
```

should be

```
i<f_n.size() && i<s_n.size()
```

otherwise you're out of bounds on one of the strings. For example if `f_n` is length 3, and `s_n` is length 5 `3 < 3 || 3 < 5` will evaluate to true and you'll index `f_n[3]` which is out of bounds.

P.S: In reality though you probably want to extract the check into a function and loop on both strings separately, otherwise the longest of the two strings won't be checked completely.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I don't know why a negative vote!! Anyway a +1 for you.

Comment: this solution assume that first name and second name have the same length!

Comment: @Neska No it doesn't. Read *all* of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate `f_n` and `s_n` separately, or it will only work if they are of equal length.

This looks like a "learn how to separate things into functions" exercise, so something like this, perhaps:

```
bool valid_character(c)
{
   // return true if c is a valid character, false otherwise.
}

bool valid_name(string name)
{
   // true if all the characters in name are valid.
}

Person(string f_n, string s_n, int a)
{
   if (!valid_name(f_n))
   {
      error("Bad first name");
   }
   if (!valid_name(s_name))
   {
      error("Bad second name");
   }

   if(a < 0 || a >=150) 
   {
       error ("Bad age!");
   }

   first_name = f_n;
   second_name = s_n;
   age = a;
}
```

Some parts left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, you want to check whether f_n and s_n contain any 'bad character', you can not check them in one loop on if you are sure that they have the same length.
so, I advise that you should check f_n and s_n respectively. 
i

---

In addition, 
if((f_n[i]>'a' && f_n[i]<'z') || (f_n[i]>'A' && f_n[i]<'Z'))
by doing this, you can make sure that f_n[i] is a 'good character', Probably,(I don't really know what's your mean about 'bad character' and 'good character'.)

Good Luck!